# how to write a code about perfect numbers in python?

Tags: python

I was trying to write a code including a function in order to find numbers that are complete(perfect number:the number which is = its denominator's summation)
but I had some problem with it...would you help me?

```
L=[]
def denominator(n):

    k=1
    while(int(k) < int(n)):
        s=int(n%k)
        if(s==0):
            L+=[s]
    k+1
    return L

def isPerfect(n):

    return denominator(n)
    a=sum(L)
    return(a==n)   

n=input("enter a number:")

if(isPerfect(n)):

    print("it is perfect.")
else:
    print("it's not perfect.")
```

Comment: your ```k+1``` seems to be outside the while loop. And it should be ```k += 1```

Comment: you have two return statements in ```isPerfect```

Comment: @Anis: And additionally `k+1` won't do anything meaningful even if it was in the loop.

Comment: Yes indeed, I haven't even paid attention to the fact it didn't actually increment anyhting x).

Comment: You should declare ```L``` within the denominator function

Comment: 0 is not a perfect number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a lot of mistakes in your code. `L` has to be defined in `denominator`; you has to add `k` not `s` to `L`; in `while` you has to increment `k`; `denominator` has to return list of dividers; you has to convert `n` to int after input and it is enough to check dividers until [n/2+1]. After removing these misprints your code will work:

```
def denominator(n):
    L = []
    k=1
    while(k < int(n/2.+1)):
        if(n%k==0):
            L+=[k,]
        k=k+1
    return L

def isPerfect(n):
    L = denominator(n)
    a=sum(L)
    return(a==n)   

n=input("enter a number:")

if(isPerfect(int(n))):
    print("it is perfect.")
else:
    print("it's not perfect.")
```

However you may reduce your code like:

```
def isPerfect(n):  
    if (n < 1): return False
    sum = 0  
    for k in range(1, int(n/2+1)):  
        if n % k == 0:  
            sum += k  
    return sum == n  
print(isPerfect(6), isPerfect(28))
```

Comment: n <= 0 are not perfect numbers, and it seems to me like your code would return True.

Comment: @Serenity Thank you .you were  so helpful .it was solved..thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

With @Serenity's answer and the comments to your post I think you have all that you need to correct the errors in your code. Let me also give you this nearly one-liner that does what you want:

```
def is_perfect(n):
    return False if n <= 0 else (sum([s for s in range(1, n) if n%s == 0]) == n)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, this is more pythonic code for this problem:

```
if sum([x for x in range(1,n) if n%x==0])==n and n>0:
     print "complete"
else:
     print " Not complete"
```

Comment: Same comment as for Serinity. Perfect numbers are positive. Check your code for ```n==0```, it won't give the right answer.